# Debug python on WSL with Visual Code

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Python installed on the Windows subsystem for Linux (WSL).

I want to debug Python code from Visual Code.

I can specify `bash` as a terminal or debug Python installed on a remote Linux box but is it possible to debug Python code running under WSL?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use the default Python Debugger? It works independently from the integrated terminal and works just fine.

Comment: for me this is relevant question too. 
and answer - because i don't want to depend on windows os. and yes, i cannot install different host os on my workstation, because it is prohibite, but wsl allows me to use native env.